# Merging/append values from different ID inside foreach() loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I am not sure if I have a correct title, but here I go. I currently develop application with CodeIgniter. Lets say I have a database object with current record:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
-- ID -- SurveyID  -- UserID  -- Value1  -- Value2  -- Marker --
----------------------------------------------------------------
--  1 --     1     --    1    --    5    --    3    --    A   --
--  2 --     1     --    1    --    5    --    3    --    B   --
--  3 --     1     --    1    --    5    --    1    --    C   --
--  4 --     1     --    1    --    5    --    3    --    D   --
--  5 --     1     --    1    --    5    --    3    --    E   --
--  6 --     2     --    2    --   10    --    7    --    A   --
--  7 --     2     --    2    --   10    --    7    --    B   --
--  8 --     2     --    2    --   10    --    7    --    C   --
--  9 --     2     --    2    --   10    --    7    --    D   --
-- 10 --     2     --    2    --   10    --    7    --    E   --
-- 11 --     2     --    3    --   12    --    17   --    A   --
-- 12 --     2     --    3    --   12    --    17   --    B   --
-- 13 --     2     --    3    --   12    --    17   --    C   --
-- 14 --     2     --    3    --   12    --    17   --    D   --
-- 15 --     2     --    3    --   12    --    17   --    E   --
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a code which generate table output from the database:

```
$tableOutput = '
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Survey ID = '.$user_data_list->SurveyID.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
';

foreach ($object as $user_data_list)
{
    $tableOutput .= '<tr>'; // Row opening
    $tableOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value1.'</td>'; // Marker A value1
    $tableOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value1.'</td>'; // Marker B value1
    $tableOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value1.'</td>'; // Marker C value1
    $tableOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value1.'</td>'; // Marker D value1
    $tableOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value1.'</td>'; // Marker E value1

    $tableOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value2.'</td>'; // Marker A value2
    $tableOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value2.'</td>'; // Marker B value2
    $tableOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value2.'</td>'; // Marker C value2
    $tableOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value2.'</td>'; // Marker D value2
    $tableOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value2.'</td>'; // Marker E value2
    $tableOutput .= '<tr>'; // Row closing
}

$tableOutput .= '</table>';
```

Which will generates:

```
----------------------------------------------------
-- Survey ID = 1                                  --
----------------------------------------------------
-- A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E --
----------------------------------------------------
-- 5 -- 5 -- 5 -- 5 -- 5 -- 3 -- 3 -- 1 -- 3 -- 3 --
----------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------
-- Survey ID = 2                                  --
----------------------------------------------------
-- A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E --
----------------------------------------------------
--10 --10 --10 --10 --10 -- 7 -- 7 -- 7 -- 7 -- 7 --
----------------------------------------------------
--12 --12 --12 --12 --12 --17 --17 --17 --17 --17 --
----------------------------------------------------
```

Table above looks fine but I have a problem with Survey ID 2. The output must be in a single row because it is a result based on all result of UserID 2 and 3. This is my expected output:

```
----------------------------------------------------
-- Survey ID = 1                                  --
----------------------------------------------------
-- A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E --
----------------------------------------------------
-- 5 -- 5 -- 5 -- 5 -- 5 -- 3 -- 3 -- 1 -- 3 -- 3 --
----------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------
-- Survey ID = 2                                  --
----------------------------------------------------
-- A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E --
----------------------------------------------------
--22 --22 --22 --22 --22 --24 --24 --24 --24 --24 --
----------------------------------------------------
```

How do I code inside the foreach() so can I make the expected output? I hope there is nothing wrong with the database design.

UPDATE: http://pastebin.com/ZYyJD6fA >> Here is the $object values. You will notice the difference between $object values and question above. The question above is the simplified version. The important columns are: `survey_id`, `user_id`, `value1`, `value2`, and `marker`. The rest is not important.

Thanks!

Comment: can u var_dump($object) and append it to question.

Comment: @Nouphal.M Hello, I've been updated the question with link to $object values. I can't paste here because exceeds maximum character of post.

Answer (score 0):

With each iteration of the foreach loop, you were not clearing out the previous iteration values. 
    $tableOutput .= '';

Change the foreach to the following:

```
 foreach ($object as $user_data_list)
    {
        $tableRowOutput = '<tr>'; // Row opening
        $tableRowOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value1.'</td>'; // Marker A value1
        $tableRowOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value1.'</td>'; // Marker B value1
        $tableRowOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value1.'</td>'; // Marker C value1
        $tableRowOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value1.'</td>'; // Marker D value1
        $tableRowOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value1.'</td>'; // Marker E value1

        $tableRowOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value2.'</td>'; // Marker A value2
        $tableRowOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value2.'</td>'; // Marker B value2
        $tableRowOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value2.'</td>'; // Marker C value2
        $tableRowOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value2.'</td>'; // Marker D value2
        $tableRowOutput .= '<td>'.$user_data_list->Value2.'</td>'; // Marker E value2
        $tableRowOutput .= '<tr>'; // Row closing

        $tableOutput .= $tableRowOutput;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @raj. Gonna try after break from long straight 10 hours programming @___@. Will comment back if I have troubles.

Answer (score 0):

how bout make like this.
create new function for the output?

```
<?php
/*
PLEASE TRY BETTER SOLUTION
*/
for($SurveyID=1;$SurveyID<=2;$SurveyID++)
{
    $tableOutput = '
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>Survey ID = '.$SurveyID.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
    ';
    echo $tableOutput;
    $s='<tr>';

    $aksara=array('','A','B','C','D','E'); 
    for($i1=1;$i1<=2;$i1++)
    {
        for($i2=1;$i2<count($aksara);$i2++)
        {
            $s.="<td>".$this->userdata_model
                     ->valueSurvei($SurveyID,$i1,$aksara[$i2])."</td>\n";
        }

    }

    $s.="</tr></table>";
    echo $s;
}

//==========================userdata_model.php======
function valueSurvei($survei, $pos, $marker)
{
    $field=$pos==1?'Value1':'Value2';
    $sql="select sum($field) s from table where SurveyID=$survei and Marker ='$marker'";
    $dt=$this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
    return $dt['s'];
}
```